# How to insert a dataframe into another dataframe with different Schema?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Dataframe A and B have different Schemas, I want to insert the rows in A to B.

The environment is Spark 1.6, so unionAll function could be used when two dataframe has the same columns in the same order.

Schema for A:

```
root
  |--a
  |--b
```

Schema for B:

```
root
  |--a
  |--b
  |--c
  |--d
  |  |--d_1
  |  |--d_2
  |  |--d_3
```

I need to insert the column "a" and "b" to dataframe B and leave other column blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the **a** and **b** column pairs are unique you can outer join the DataFrames.

```
B.join(A, usingColumns = Seq("a", "b"), "outer")
```

If they are not you can append a unique column and then do outer join

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

B.withColumn("id", lit(2)).join(A.withColumn("id", lit(1)), usingColumns = Seq("id"), "outer")
```

Comment: I tried something like "B.join(A , B("a") === A("a"), "outer")".printSchema, the result show there are 6 columns: a,b,c,d(d_1,d_2,d_3),a,b. The "a" and "b" columns are duplicated

Comment: @PingjiangLi
Spark has multiple API for join. The one you are using keeps the column on which you are joining from both DataFrame. The one that I suggested will not create a duplicate column. So it will look something like this,

`B.join(A, usingColumns = Seq("a"), "outer")`


But as you have a column b in both DataFrame and you are not considering b when you are joining the end schema will look something like this a,b,c,d(d_1,d_2,d_3),b